# Generating device UDID vs. saving it in Android

Tags: android

Which is better:
1- Generate device UDID on each app launch (taking into consideration it doesn't change for the same device)?
2- Or generate device UDID on first launch then store it (in SharedPreferences for example) then fetch it from the storage on subsequent runs?

Comment: Could you give some background on what you are trying to achieve. Both strategies could have pros and contras.

Comment: For analytics purposes, we send the device's udid with different events.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to rely on GCM token value called InstanceId(IID). You can read the advantage of it in [Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2015/05/a-closer-look-at-google-play-services-75.html).

It gives you unique id per each app per each device and will notify [when it is changed](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceIDListenerService) (added in GCM 7.5).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm asking sth different. I need to know whether it's better to generate the id (regardless of how it's generated) on each launch, versus generating it on first launch then saving it in a storage area and reading it from the storage area on each subsequent launch.

Comment: @SaryAssad // I'd say, _on first launch then saving it_ is better as it is no need to generate at each time. Generate at each time approach might give you discontinuous analysis data input which will be unwanted result to you IMHO.